# Does the Mechaber, banning meat at seudah mafseket, mean it's okay beforehand?

Tags: halacha, meat, shulchan-aruch, nine-days, tisha-bav

[The mechaber](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1693) writes that we have the custom one can't eat, during the seudah mafseket, salted meat even over two days and one night.  Does that mean that during the nine days it would be permissable?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you would link the Mechaber into your question or at a minimum give the location.

Comment: The sefardim do until shavua schal bah, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 5):

If you see the [Mishna Brurah in Siman 552](http://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%91_%D7%90) he writes that's from the din of gemara,but regarding minhag its assur from Rosh Chodesh